# spring rest project with client side in angular js - how to approach the rest service with ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

So I have a spring rest project that includes client side app.
I can run the service on a local tomcat and get responses querying "http://:8080/books" for example.
I can set app an apache server and go to "http://" to see my client app (the apache htdocs dir points to the project client app dir).

What I can't manage to do is send ajax rest queries to the service.
I'm using angular js so it looks like:
$http.get("http://:8080/books").success(...).error(...);
and it always enters the error callback method.

In the debugger/network tab I see that the request status is "canceled". Looking at the request's details I see next to the "Request headers" title the message: "CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown".

Here is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Library Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.library.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>prod</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.library.service.config.ControllerConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My project structure is:

- src

  - main

    - java
    - resources
    - webapp

      - resources
      - WEB-INF
  - test

Is it because the origin is different (mainly the port)?
Should I add some code to my web.xml to serve the client through tomcat? If so how?

thanks.

Comment: Note that Tomcat is also an apache project, are you saying you're running Apache webserver and Apache tomcat both?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a problem with cross-domain requests(yes, different port is another domain for the browser and it will cancel the request for security purposes if server will not include cross-domain headers). Try to add this headers to your REST response:

```
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

if you need cookies you might need this as well:

```
responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

in the second case you have to set an origin, '*' will not work in this case

more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Angular http uses relative urls.

For example using : `www.stackoverflow.com`

And

```
$http.get('/api/search?'
```

would call : `www.stackoverflow.com/api/search`

You can tests your rest api using your browser for gets requests, and one of the many plugins for post/put/delete.

(they are jsut made up urls btw)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
Thanks for all the answers, I was looking for the spring solution.
+1 JohnnyAW for your answer.

In my controller config class I've extended WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overridden an addResourceHandlers method pointing to my client web app dir:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.library.service")
public class ControllerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
}
```

Note that it works because configuration is annotated with @EnableWebMvc.